# TypeError: Error #1006: addEventListener is not a function. (Actionscript, puzzle game)

Tags: actionscript-3

AS3 newbie here (like really new). I'm trying to make a puzzle game with actionscript, and below is the code: (put in an as file applied to fla)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main2 extends MovieClip
    {
        var xPos:int;
        var yPos:int;

        public function Main2():void
        {
            trace(r1c1, r1c2, r1c3, r1c4, r2c1, r2c2, r2c3, r2c4, r3c1, r3c2, r3c3, r3c4);
            addListeners(r1c1, r1c2, r1c3, r1c4, r2c1, r2c2, r2c3, r2c4, r3c1, r3c2, r3c3, r3c4);
        }

        private function getPosition(target:Object):void
        {
            xPos = target.x;
            yPos = target.y;
        }

        private function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            getPosition(e.target);

            e.target.startDrag(true);
        }

        private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("p" + e.target.name)))
            {
                e.target.x = getChildByName("p" + e.target.name).x;
                e.target.y = getChildByName("p" + e.target.name).y;
            }
            else
            {
                e.target.x = xPos;
                e.target.y = yPos;
            }

            e.target.stopDrag();
        }
    
        private function addListeners(...objects):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
            {
                objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
                objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(r1c1, r1c2...) are the puzzle pieces, instances of movie clips that are supposed to snap to position when they are dragged to the correct positions.

the code returns with:
TypeError: Error #1006: addEventListener is not a function.

I'm really new to this coding language (and coding in general, just a high school student trying to finish a project here) and I have no idea what the error means despite checking multiple posts on here. I'm really grateful for any help I receive. Cheers! :)

Comment: What is the type of objects inside the objects array (r1c1, rc1c.2...)?

Comment: They show up as class when they're traced.

Comment: `import flash.events.*;` should do. Also you likely transfer some weird array in `objects`, check that. As a means of diagnosis, `flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()` should provide you some data on what is received in that function, it's quite possible there has been a something that's not a `DisplayObject` and that one does not have an ability to listen for events.

Comment: You need to read up and learn about **classes** and **instances**: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html In simple terms a **class** is a blueprint. You **instantiate** a class to get an object to work with: to attach to display list, to show and hide, to make half-transparent, and so on. What you have in your Library are symbols bound to classes. Then, if you designed them on stage and gave them instance names identical to their class names, then it is a wrong thing to do.